# aspNet Core - identity - applicationUser, not automatically generated?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, linkedin-api

I want to create Linkedin login into a website that uses Microsoft identity framework. But i don´t know how to use the ApplicationUser, it says its missing, and i don´t want to generate a empty class. Don´t know what to do with it. should Ms identity framework create one by its self?

I have (ms studio 2017 v15.9.31) .NET framework v4.8 aspnet core app 2.1.1 , aspnetCore razor design 2.1.2 , aspnet security oauth linkedin 2.0.0

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Linkedin.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace Linkedin
{
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
       
        services.AddAuthentication().AddLinkedIn(options => {
            options.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:LinkedIn:ClientId"];
            options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:LinkedIn:ClientSecret"];
            options.Events = new OAuthEvents()
            {
                OnRemoteFailure = loginFailureHandler => 
            {

                var authProperties = options.StateDataFormat.Unprotect(loginFailureHandler.Request.Query["state"]);
                loginFailureHandler.Response.Redirect("/Account/login");
                loginFailureHandler.HandleResponse();
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
            };
        });

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });


        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            //app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    } //configure
} // startup

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to customise the User model used in the Identity framework then just use the `IdentityUser` class.  The `ApplicationUser` class (or whatever you want to call it) is usually used when adding custom properties to the User model.

Change this: `services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()` to `services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()`

More info can be found here [Customizing Identity Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-2.2#custom-user-data)